# Parsing command-line entries in C: implementing a shell

Tags: c, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm implementing a shell in C, and I ran into some problems parsing command-line entries. I want my parser method to separate command-line entries that are delimited by the whitespace character, and return the result as a double char pointer. ie, say I have "ls -l >ls.txt", my parser should return a char **r with r[0]="ls", r[1]="-l", and r[2]=">ls.txt".

Here is the code for my current parse method, which is, by the way, segfaulting, and I'm out of ideas as to how to fix that:

```
 char **parser(int *argc, char *s)
 {
     char **r;
     char *t, *m;
     int i,n,size;

     t = malloc(strlen(s)); // firs i used this instead of *r, but i run 
                            // into trouble when i have more than two
                            // argc. ( You see why, right?)
    //strcpy(t,s);
    i = 0;
    size = 5;
    r = malloc(size*sizeof(char *));
    while (( m = strchr(s, ' '))) {
        n = ((int)m) - ((int)s);
        if (i==0) {
          *r = malloc(n);
        } else {
           *r = realloc(*r, n);
        }
        strncpy(*r, s, n);
        *r[n]= '\0';
        s = (char*)(s+n+1);
        if (i == size)
            r = realloc(r, (size = 2*size)*sizeof(char*));
        i++;
        r = (char **)(r + sizeof(char*));
   }

   s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';
   if ((i<1) || (strlen(s)>1)) {
       *r = s;
   }
   *argcp = ++i;
   return r;
}
```

I know my code isn't ideal. It could be made better using strsep, but my main concer is how to manage memory for the double char pointer I want to return.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that in an ordinary shell, you can write `> file` or `>file` and both redirect standard output to `file`.  You can also write `ls -l|wc-l` or `ls -l | wc -l` (or mix'n'match the spacing around the pipe symbol.  That is, most shells are very flexible about where there's white space.  (Indeed, `>file ls -l` sends the output of `ls -l` to `file`; so does `ls >file -l`!)

Comment: Presentation-wise, your code would be easier to read if it was systematically indented, and didn't indulge in gratuitous tricks like `if (...) a = ...;` all on a single line.  It just makes it hard to read your code.  If you want help, you want to make sure your code is easy for other people to read.

Comment: There's a world of trouble in the lines `n = ((int)m) - ((int)s);
        if(i==0){
          *r = malloc(n);
        }else{
          *r = realloc(*r, n);
        }`  The first line should be `n = (int)(m - s);` (or you could omit the cast).  The space you `malloc()` or `realloc()` in `r` is supposed to be an array of `char *` values (that's why you used `char **r` to declare it).  The space allocated needs to be the number of `char *` values, and the size needs to be scaled by `sizeof(*r)`.  You then are mismanaging the string handling horribly.  Time to redo from first principles.

Comment: Thanks for that first comment! I'm going to fix that in the parser right now!

Comment: You need a (growing) array of `char *` values, pointed at by a `char **` (so `r` is OK as a variable definition). For each entry in the array, you need a string that's long enough for the characters plus a null terminator.  The string will be pointed at by an entry in the `r` array: `r[i] = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);` or similar.  Or, better, use or implement `strdup()`.

Comment: I used `r[i] = malloc(strlen(str)+1` to fix it, it's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick stab.

My C is so rusty, all of the hinges are stuck, so.

The premise is that you will end up with a pointer to an array of pointers. The key detail though, is at the end of that list of pointers, is the argument data itself. So when you're done, you simply need to free the returned pointer.

Untested. There may well be a one off error sneaking in here.

Edit, I compiled and quickly tested it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char **parser(int *argc, char *s) {
    char **r, **rp;
    char *t, *p, *w;
    void *vp;
    int l;

    l = strlen(s); // size of cmd line
    vp = malloc(l + (*argc * sizeof(char *))); // total buffer size
    t = (char *)(vp + (*argc * sizeof(char *))); // offset into buffer for argument copy
    r = (char **)vp;  // start of buffer, start of pointer array to arguments
    strcpy(t, s);  // copy arguments in to buffer
    p = t;  // parsing pointer
    w = t;  // word pointer for each argument
    rp = r;  // storage for first pointer

    while(*p) {  // while not at end of string
        if (*p == ' ') {  // if we find a space
            if (w) {  // if we have a word pointer assigned
                *rp++ = w;  // store the word pointer
                w = NULL;  // set word pointer to null
                *p = '\0';  // terminate argument with a 0
            } // else do nothing continue to skip spaces
        } else {
            if (w == NULL) {  // If we haven't got a new arg yet
                w = p;  // set it
            }  // otherwise, just keep scanning
        }
        p++;  // move along the string
    }
    if (w) {  // clean up at the end if we have an arg
        *rp++ = w;
        w = NULL;  // no reason to set 0 at the end, it's already there from strcpy
    }

    return r;
}

int main() {
    char *cmd = "arg1 arg2";
    int argc = 2;

    char **r = parser(&argc, cmd);

    printf("%s\n",r[0]);
    printf("%s\n",r[1]);
}
```